# $T:V \to V$ if $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ what about $\{Tv_1,...Tv_2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I see a prove which uses something like this:

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation.

Let $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a base for $V$.

Can i conclude that $\{Tv_1,..,Tv_n\}$ is also a base for $V$.

If so, what about the case when $kerT \neq \{0\}$?

And how do we prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself: If $\ker(T)\neq \{0\}$, then $Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_n$ is not a basis.

Comment: Consider the obvious extreme $T:V\to V$ defined by $ T(v_i)=\vec0$ for all $i$

Answer (score 1):

if $\{v_{1} , v_{2},..., v_{n}\}$ is a basis of $\ V$ and  $ \ T:\ V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation then obviously  $\{T(v_{1}) , T(v_{2}),..., T(v_{n})\}$ is a generating set for $Im(T)$ ie: $Im(T)=vect(T(v_{1}) , T(v_{2}),..., T(v_{n}))$ now we know that:
$$\dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=dim(V)$$
thus having $Ker(T)=\{ 0_{\ V} \}\implies dim(Im(T))=dim(V)\implies V=Im(T)$

Comment: +1, but in my rememberings, the formula $\dim(Ker(T))+\dim(Im(T)) = \dim(V)$ is proved using OP claim.

Comment: the formula $dim(ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=dim(V)$ is true for any linear endomorphisme

Comment: Yes, but how do you prove it? The proof I know for this formula uses the conclusion of the question asked.

Comment: $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ is obviously a generating set for $\mathrm{Im}(T)$. It need *not* be a basis, i.e. it need not be linearly independent.

Comment: @Thorgott This is not my point. My point is about the formula $\dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=dim(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose that $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.
  Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(v_i)=0$ and set $w=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$. By linearity of $T$, we have
  $$0= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(v_i)= \sum_{i=1}^n T(a_i v_i)=T(w).$$
  As $\ker(T)=\{0\}$, $T(w)=0$ implies that $w=0$ and thus $a_1=\ldots=a_n=0$. Therefore $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ is linearly independent. Finally, $n=\dim(V)$ implies that $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ is a basis of $V$.
- Suppose that $\ker(T)\neq \{0\}$. Let $u\in\ker(T), u \neq 0$. Let $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ be such that $u=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i v_i$. Then, we have 
  $$0=T(u) = \sum_{i=1}^n T(b_i v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i T(v_i).$$
  As $u\neq 0$ not all $b_i$ are $0$ and thus $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ is not linearly independent. Hence, $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ is not a basis of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. Injectivity does not guarantee that the image of a basis is still a basis when $V$ is infinite dimensional.

For example, let $V= \ell^2$, $v_i = (0,...,1,0,...)$ be the standard Schauder basis, and $T$ be the right shift operator defined by $(v_1, v_2,...) \mapsto(0,v_1,v_2,...)$. This is clearly injective and linear but $(1,0,...)$ is not in the image of $T$.

Comment: Well, OP assumes that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$. Unless $n=\infty$ (which is a quite unusual notation), this implies that $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: I know. I figured that a setting where the rank nullity theorem fails is conceptually useful in part for understanding the finite dimensional case better.

Comment: Good point (+1). Although, it may be that OP has not dealt with many infinite dimensional vector spaces yet :).